# Get li text on basis of its attribute from ul

Tags: jquery

I have below `HTML` structure

```
<ul id="MyUl">
    <li class="JustAnotherClass">Not Desired</li>
    <li class="JustAnotherClass" >Not Desired</li>
    <li class="Selected-Item Another-class" aria-selected="true">Desired Element</li>
    <li class="JustAnotherClass">Not Desired</li>
    <li class="JustAnotherClass">Not Desired</li>
    <li class="JustAnotherClass">Not Desired</li>
    <li class="JustAnotherClass">Not Desired</li>
</ul>
```

The classes of `li` can be repeated anywhere on the `HTML` page.
I am looking for `JQuery` to get me the text of `li` having `class "SelectedItem"`.

Please guide me through it.

Comment: `$('#MyUl > li.SelectedItem').text()`

Comment: https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/faq/how-do-i-select-an-item-using-class-or-id/

Comment: Question exhibits a serious lack of research effort

Comment: @Satpal: Got Variable not found error. Does hyphen in class name or having multiple classes effects in anyway?

Comment: @charlietfl: Next time I will be more careful. Thanks for the feedback

Comment: _hyphen in class name_ does matter use correct class name

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
 var x = document.getElementsByClassName("SelectedItem");
alert (x[0].innerHTML);
```